# Eclipse PyDev run remotely

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, remote-debugging

I normally have to log into to a cluster and switch to a node / user:

```
ssh root@domain
ssh n001
su - user
```

and then I am able to run from a particular directory and debug my code. I would like to use Eclipse PyDev (locally) to run/debug my code on the cluster (seems it would be much more useful then using IPython.embed() everywhere.)

I've searched on stackoverflow and haven't found an answer I can follow easily. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
J.

Comment: Are you asking how to run the graphical Eclipse environment remotely?

Comment: No. I am running the Eclipse environment on my local PC. My project folders are on the cluster. I have access to the folders since I mounted the cluster drive and I can edit these projects using Eclipse. However, I don't have the ability to run the projects directly on the cluster using Eclipse. I use the terminal to do that.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look to [this](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html). I haven't used it myself, but I find the setup you propose could be very useful. Hope it helps.